# glassfish - Unknown error when trying port 4848

Tags: windows-xp, glassfish

I'm installing glassfish 3.1 on Windows XP service pack 3. but in configuration step it gives this error:

```
PERFORMING THE REQUIRED CONFIGURATIONS
______________________________________

CREATING DOMAIN
_______________
Executing command :C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat --user admin --passwordfile C:\DOCUME~1\MAJIDA~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\glassfish-3.1-windows-ml.exe6\asadminTmp1079044298673991344.tmp create-domain --savelogin --checkports=false --adminport 4848 --instanceport 8080 --domainproperties=jms.port=7676:domain.jmxPort=8686:orb.listener.port=3700:http.ssl.port=8181:orb.ssl.port=3820:orb.mutualauth.port=3920 domain1
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat --user admin --passwordfile C:\DOCUME~1\MAJIDA~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\glassfish-3.1-windows-ml.exe6\asadminTmp5898014821156752751.tmp create-domain --savelogin --checkports=false --adminport 4848 --instanceport 8080 --domainproperties=jms.port=7676:domain.jmxPort=8686:orb.listener.port=3700:http.ssl.port=8181:orb.ssl.port=3820:orb.mutualauth.port=3920 domain1Unknown error when trying port 4848.  Try a different port number.
Command create-domain failed.
CLI130 Could not create domain, domain1
```

I change `4848` to any other port. but it doesn't work. firewall is completely disabled.
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Just download this package in .zip :) this will solve your problem. (Mine too)

From page: http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.1-final.html

Click for example here: http://download.java.net/glassfish/3.1.1/release/glassfish-3.1.1.zip